# Bi-directional arrow in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, polyline-creation

I'm using Leaflet to create a map of movements of a species of interest.
I'm using polylineDecorator to draw arrows, but I would like to have a bi-directional arrow (example in figure below).

[image: Bi-directional arrow]

Right now my code for a single arrowhead looks like that:

```
       function pop_Seasonal_0(feature, layer) {
          var PD1 = L.polyline(layer.getLatLngs(), {
               color: "#8B0000",weight: 5,opacity: 1,dashArray: '4,12,20,12'
          }).addTo(layer_Seasonal_0);

          L.polylineDecorator(PD1, {
            patterns: [{
              offset: '110%',
              repeat: 0,
              symbol: L.Symbol.arrowHead({
                pixelSize: 20,
                pathOptions: {
                  color: "#8B0000",
                  fillOpacity: 1,
                  weight: 0
                }
              })
            }]
          }).addTo(layer_Seasonal_0);
        }
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PolylineDecorator plugin out of the box does not offer possibility of changing directon of the arrow. To achieve this, `L.Symbol.ArrowHead` object has to be extended with modification of call to internal `_buildArrowPath` method that takes care of arrow creation.

In the modified call parameter that tells about polyline direction is modified by adding 180 degrees:

```
L.Symbol.ArrowHead.Opposite = L.Symbol.ArrowHead.extend({
  _buildArrowPath: function(dirPoint, map) {
    dirPoint.heading += 180;
    return L.Symbol.ArrowHead.prototype._buildArrowPath.call(this, dirPoint, map);
  }
});

L.Symbol.arrowHead.opposite = function(options) {
  return new L.Symbol.ArrowHead.Opposite(options);
}
```

Creating of line with arrows in both directions then looks like this:

```
var arrowSymbol = L.Symbol.arrowHead({pixelSize: 15, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}});
var oppositeArrowSymbol = L.Symbol.arrowHead.opposite({pixelSize: 15, polygon: false, pathOptions: {stroke: true}});

var arrow = L.polyline([[57, -19], [60, -12]], {}).addTo(map);
var arrowHead = L.polylineDecorator(arrow, {
  patterns: [
    {offset: '100%', repeat: 0, symbol: arrowSymbol},
    {offset: '0%', repeat: 0, symbol: oppositeArrowSymbol}
  ]
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like a charm! :)